# How to use jq to give true or false when uri field is present in my output json

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON which goes like this:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "uri":"www.xxx.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

**EDIT**
When uri is not present, JSON looks like this:

```
{
"results":[

]
}
```

In some cases, uri is present and in some cases, it is not.
Now, I want to use jq to return boolean value if uri is present or not.

This is what I wrote so far but despite uri being present, it gives null.
${search_query_response} contains the JSON

```
file_status=$(jq -r '.uri' <<< ${search_query_response})
```

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Show what JSON looks like when uri is not present.

Comment: also to find the uri in your string you'll need something like `jq ".results[].uri"` not just `.uri`

Comment: @Cyrus I added how, the JSON will look like when uri is not present.

Comment: @lwileczek, Thanks for your suggestion.
But in my case, I don't want the value of uri. I just want a boolean if uri is present or not.

Comment: `jq -e`, see `man jq`: > `-e` / `--exit-status`: Sets the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value  was  either
           false  or  null, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system
           error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.

Comment: Please  be explicit about whether or not the .results array might have more than one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `has` function does the job:

```sh
jq '.results|map(has("uri"))|.[]'
```

`map` the `has` function on `.results`.

Answer (score 7):

Since you use `jq`, it means you are working within a shell script context.

If the boolean result is to be handled by the shell script, you can make `jq` set its `EXIT_CODE` depending on the JSON request success or failure status, with `jq -e`

Example shell script using the `EXIT_CODE` from `jq`:

```sh
if uri=$(jq -je '.results[].uri') <<<"$search_query_response"
then
  printf 'Search results contains an URI: %s.\n' "$uri"
else
  echo 'No URI in search results.'
fi
```

---

See `man jq`:

> - `-e` / `--exit-status`:
>
>   Sets the exit status of `jq` to `0` if the last output values was neither `false` nor `null`, `1` if the last output value was either `false` or `null`, or `4` if no valid result was ever produced. Normally `jq` exits with `2` if there was any usage problem or system error, `3` if there was a `jq` program compile error, or `0` if the `jq` program ran.
>
>   Another way to set the exit status is with the `halt_error` builtin function.